# Play multiple .m3u8 videos in single HTML file

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm working on a project where I need to display multiple video streams on a single html file ( more like a CCTV page ). The video source would be something like "***[http://10.66.123.1/streams/1/hls/stream.m3u8***"](http://10.66.123.1/streams/1/hls/stream.m3u8***%22) and the video extension is "***m3u8***", so I have figured it out that I can use "hls.js" and it is working fine.

Now when I can play a single video, I want to play multiple videos. At a time, that's where I'm facing the issue.

Here is the HTML + JAVASCRIPT code that I'm working on ( I have also attached the codepen link at the bottom)

```
     <main>
      <section class="video-section">
        <h1>PLAY VIDEO</h1>
        <div id="player">
          <video id="video" width="500" height="300" controls muted></video>
        </div>
      </section>
<!-- Other screen will go here -->
      <section class="video-playlist">
        <div class="flex-container">

              <div class="flex-item stream">
                <video id="video0" width="400" height="300" controls muted></video>
              </div>
              
              <div class="flex-item stream">
                <video id="video1" width="300" height="300" controls muted></video>
              </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>

<script>
  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
   
    var hls = new Hls();
    
    hls.loadSource("https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8");
    hls.attachMedia(video);

    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
      video.play();          
    });
  } 
</script>
```

**Code Pen Link**
**https://codepen.io/nutkani-the-reactor/pen/vYRQwxo**

Any hint will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var hls2 = new Hls();

hls2.loadSource("https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8");
hls2.attachMedia(video);
```